# Contains filter on Microsoft Graph query not working

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to user the *contains* filter on a /users query, like this for example:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=contains(displayName, 'Garth')

However, this results in a *BadRequest* response saying "An unknown function with name 'contains' was found. This may also be a key lookup on a navigation property, which is not allowed."

According to the OData 4.0 specs, the contains filter should be available though. Is there a way to use a contains filter on a list of users?

Comment: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$search="displayName:Garth"

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `contains` function is not available for users. `startsWith` is available though.
e.g. [`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=startswith(displayName,'Garth')`](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=startswith(displayName,'Garth')).

Comment: And in 2022 it's still the case. Whilst not wanting to shoot the messenger, this isn't really the same thing at all. How MS thought this was acceptable is frankly baffling.

Answer (score 6):

Additionally you can try the people API (this is only available on /beta).  This supports $search AND will do fuzzy and phonetic matching.
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/people?$search=Garth

Comment: This search happens only through your contact list (or maybe through email search). But results are really strange and looks not relevant for me. It is not looking for people through out all your tenant

Comment: That is correct - people is about the people you communicate with most often.  Currently it does not allow search across all users in your tenant.  Marek's point is valid - we don't support search for users - only the startswith filter.  You could file a request for this on UserVoice - https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/category/101632-microsoft-graph-o365-rest-apis

Comment: I'm surprised that this is not implemented yet...

Comment: And now the user voice has vanished. Link broken

Answer (score 0):

$search can replace $contains
for example to show all the users that their names may contain the string  "sa"
[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$count=true&$search="givenName:sa"](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$count=true&$search=%22givenName:sa%22)

```
  "value": [
        {....
           
            "givenName": "Sammy",
          ..... 
        },
        {
           .....
            "givenName": "Sabrina",
           .......
        },


.....
```