# Is there a way to use $filter in Microsoft Graph to return users in the organization filter by display name that CONTAINS a specified string?

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

I have checked the following documentation, unsuccessfully:

https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/overview/query_parameters#filter

The documentation above also mention:

"These parameters are compatible with the OData V4 query language."

Checking OData V4 query language, I have not found anything either:

http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata03/os/complete/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.0-errata03-os-part2-url-conventions-complete.html#_Toc453752356

I also checked this:

[Contains filter on Microsoft Graph query not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35557280/contains-filter-on-microsoft-graph-query-not-working)

I would need something lik this:

Considering an user and its displayName equals to "Pedro", I need to find a way to use $filter (or any other possibility within Microsoft Graph) to return it as part of the response it if I write "edr" or any other substring. startswith and endswith do not fits in my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the filtering is generally pretty limited in Microsoft Graph for directory resources.  Contains queries (substrings/full-text searches, or $search) are not available for directory resources - the only thing possible is a full match or startswith filter.  Please file a request for search/contains capability on User Voice - https://officespdev.uservoice.com/.

It would be great to understand your scenario a little better to know why startswith filter doesn't work for you.

Hope this helps,

Comment: @dan-kershaw-msft thanks for the answer. Is it not possible on Azure AD Graph (graph.windows.net) either?

Comment: The same limitation is present in AAD Graph. I'm afraid the limitation is in the core underlying directory service and its store.  AAD Graph and Microsoft Graph are simply API layers on top of services like the directory service.