# AAD B2C: Search Users by PrincipalName

Tags: .net, azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I have followed the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#example-2-get-a-user-account-using-a-sign-in-name) to find a registered User by Sign In Name.

The sample shows the following code to return any user with a Sign In Name `j.smith@yahoo.com`:

```cs
var users = await graphClient.Users
    .Request()
    .Filter("identities/any(c:c/issuerAssignedId eq 'j.smith@yahoo.com' and c/issuer eq 'contoso.onmicrosoft.com')")
    .GetAsync();
```

Now I am trying to implement a search, which should search users without entering the full `signInName`. Since the filter appears to be OData, I tried to enhance it using the `contains` method:

```cs
var users = await graphClient.Users
    .Request()
    .Filter($"identities/any(c:contains(c/issuerAssignedId,'j.smith') and c/issuer eq 'contoso.onmicrosoft.com') ")
    .Top(5)
    .GetAsync();
```

Now I receive the following error when I run this new query:

```
Status Code: BadRequest
Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: Code: Request_BadRequest
Message: An unknown function with name 'contains' was found. This may also be a key lookup on a navigation property, which is not allowed.
```

Do I have a typo somewhere or is `contains` not allowed? I don't think the `issuerAssignedId` is a lookup or a navigation property. Since I'm working with Azure AD B2C, the `$search` function is also not working according to the same documentation page, so I am now stuck.

***What is the way to search users in Azure AD B2C?***

#### Edit

I have found two more StackOverflow articles talking about this, but they are quite old. In [one of them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41787886/2632991), a Microsoft employee points out that one could use the `startswith` operator.

I have tried implementing it like this, but it also throws an error.

```cs
.Filter($"identities/any(a:startswith(a/issuerAssignedId,'{username}') and a/issuer eq '{issuer}') ")
```

```
Status Code: BadRequest
Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: Code: Request_BadRequest
Message: Unsupported property or property value or combination of property and operation occured
```

**More sources**:

- [OData Contains Specification](https://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata03/os/complete/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.0-errata03-os-part2-url-conventions-complete.html#_Toc444868695)

Comment: Hi, have you ever got to make this work? I now have to do something very similar and I face the same issue as you did back in 2021.

Comment: @DariusPintilie no, sorry... I have synchronized my AAD B2C Users to my own database where I can query.

Comment: Understood, thanks a lot for your fast answer! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

With the note that `contains` operator is currently [not supported on any MS Graph queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#filter-parameter), there is a workaround with `startsWith`.

The Microsoft Graph implementation for lookup the `identities` property is limited to providing exact values for **both** `issuerAssignedId` and `issuer`.

A workaround that I have implemented is to keep the `issuerAssignedId` in additional extension attribute. This is relatively easy to implement if you use custom policies. But if you use user flows, it will be error prone as there is no direct way to record this value as additional attribute. You have to, basically, constantly query MS Graph for [(delta at best!) users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/delta-query-users) and update custom attribute based on issuerAssignedId.

Answer (score 1):

I use the following code to get the User by a username or login email to query the Azure AD B2C.

```
  string usernameOrEmail = "some@email.com";
  string aadB2CIssuerDomain = "yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com";

  public async Task<User[]> GetGraphApiUsersByUsernameEmail(string usernameOrEmail)
  {
    var users = await _graphServiceClient
    .Users
    .GetAsync(requestConfiguration =>
    {
      requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Filter = $"identities/any(c:c/issuerAssignedId eq '{usernameOrEmail}' and c/issuer eq '{aadB2CIssuerDomain}')";
    });

     

    foreach (var user in users.Value.ToList().Select(e => new
    {
      e.DisplayName,
      e.Id,
      e.Identities,
      e.Mail,
      e.UserPrincipalName,

    }))
    {
      Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user));
    }

    return users?.Value.ToArray();
  }
```

Hope it helps.
Kind regards